# python requests post file return null

Tags: python, python-requests

I need help with python requests. I want to post a file to a server. Here is my example code for posting the file

```
import requests

with open('try.txt', 'rb') as myfile:
    url = <myurl>
    files = {'value':myfile}
    response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

`try.txt` is not a blank file. It contains some sentences

On the server side, here is the snippet for receiving the file.

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

class MyThing(Resource):
    def get(self):
        pass

    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('value')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        value = args['value']

        if value.endswith(".txt") or value.endswith(".csv"):
            ## do something

        else:
            ## do something
```

However when I run the server and try to post the file to the server, it return an error saying that

```
    if value.endswith(".txt") or value.endswith(".csv"):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

I check the `value` by `print files` and it return like this

```
{'value': <open file 'try.txt', mode 'rb' at 0x7f041db8e420>}
```

Does this mean `value` is `null`? or did I missed something on my server side code? Thank you for the help.

Comment: You are not passing the name of the file:  'try.txt', but the handle of the file, meaning the opened file itself. If that's what you want (and post supports it, which I have no idea), what you need is value -> value.name  , since name will be the name of the opened file

Comment: Also, it seems nothing is being received, because the error claims value is None.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems that my attempt by using `if value.endswith...` is not a good solution. May I ask if you have any idea or suggestion for above case? I want to differentiate what I want to do for certain file that been sent to the server.

Comment: I would send the filename, assuming the server has also access to it.